# Sorting gridview embedded in user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have created an asp.net usercontrol that should list users in a number of applications. For that purpose, the control renders a repeater (foreach application) which in turn renders a gridview (with users for that application).
The control renders fine, except the fact that columns in the gridview are not sortable. Nothing happens (no postback) when clicking the headers. Apparently, no JavaScript is rendered to perform the postback when clicking the header.

This is the code:

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:UserList runat=\"server\"></{0}:UserList>")]
public class UserList : WebControl
{
    #region Variables

    private Repeater list;
    private Literal heading;

    #endregion

    #region Events

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public UserList() : base()
    {
        // Default settings for list control. 
        list = new Repeater() { ID = "userList" };
        heading = new Literal() { ID = "userListHeading" };


    }

    #endregion

    #region Control event handlers

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var css = "<link href=\"" + Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(UserList), "Web.UI.Resources.CSS.UserList.css") + "\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "UserListCss", css, false); 

        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        heading.RenderControl(writer);
        list.RenderControl(writer);
        base.RenderControl(writer);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {




        // set properties
        list.ItemTemplate = new ListTemplate();

        // attach event handlers
        list.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(OnList_ItemDataBound);

        // bind data
        var allRoles = AdvancedRoleProvider.Instance.GetAllRoles();

        String appName = (Roles.ApplicationName.Equals("*") ? " alle applikationer" : Roles.ApplicationName);
        heading.Text = String.Format("<h2>{0}</h2>", "Brugere i " + appName);
        if (allRoles.Count == 0)
        {
            heading.Text += "Der kunne ikke findes nogen brugere.";
        }
        else
        {
            list.DataSource = allRoles;
            list.DataBind();
        }

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    #endregion


    #region List control event handlers

    protected void OnList_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            KeyValuePair<String, IList<String>> data = (KeyValuePair<String, IList<String>>)e.Item.DataItem;
            Literal litApplication = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litApplication");
            litApplication.Text = String.Format(litApplication.Text, data.Key);

            GridView gvUsers = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvUsers");
            gvUsers.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(OnGridViewUsers_RowDataBound);
            gvUsers.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(OnGridViewUsers_Sorting);
            gvUsers.DataSource = AdvancedRoleProvider.Instance.GetApplicationUsers(data.Key);
            gvUsers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    void OnGridViewUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void OnGridViewUsers_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Impl. sorting logic
    }




    #region List layout template

    /// <summary>
    /// Layout template class for the repeater control.
    /// </summary>
    public class ListTemplate : ITemplate
    {

        #region Constructors

        public ListTemplate()
        {


        }







        #endregion

        #region Public methods

        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            GridView gvUsers;
            gvUsers = new GridView() { ID = "gvUsers", AutoGenerateColumns = false, AllowSorting = true };

            BoundField userField = new BoundField() { HeaderText = "Bruger", DataField = "UserName", SortExpression = "UserName" };
            userField.HeaderStyle.CssClass = userField.ItemStyle.CssClass = "userName";
            BoundField fullNameField = new BoundField() { HeaderText = "Navn", DataField = "FullName", SortExpression = "FullName" };
            fullNameField.HeaderStyle.CssClass = userField.ItemStyle.CssClass = "userName";
            BoundField roleField = new BoundField() { HeaderText = "Rolle", DataField = "RoleName", SortExpression = "RoleName" };
            roleField.HeaderStyle.CssClass = roleField.ItemStyle.CssClass = "roleName";
            BoundField adField = new BoundField() { HeaderText = "AD Gruppe", DataField = "ADGroupName", SortExpression = "ADGroupName" };
            adField.HeaderStyle.CssClass = adField.ItemStyle.CssClass = "adGroupName";

            gvUsers.Columns.Add(userField);
            gvUsers.Columns.Add(fullNameField);
            gvUsers.Columns.Add(roleField);
            gvUsers.Columns.Add(adField);
            container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id=\"userList\">"));
            container.Controls.Add(new Literal() { ID = "litApplication", Text="<h3>{0}</h3>" });
            container.Controls.Add(gvUsers);
            container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
        }


        #endregion

        #region Event handlers



        #endregion

        #region Properties




        #endregion
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work or not, but you may want try adding the grid through the designer/html. Also, you may want to add the handler at the html side as well instead of the OnList_ItemDataBound. Hope this helps.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" onsorting="OnGridViewUsers_Sorting">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if you try to look at my code, you would see that it's a reusable custom control that will be distributed through a .dll, so I cannot place code in markup.